# Unique column value in django

Tags: python, django

I want the `location` to be unique within my database. If I already have a location set to `logo`, as soon as I choose another `Media` object to have location as `logo` as well, I want the previous `Media` object to have `location` 
set to `None` or some default value. Not sure how to do this or where to look in the `django` documentation

```
class Media(models.Model):
    LOCATION = (
        ("video_intro", "Video Intro"),
        ("logo", "Logo")
    )

    TYPE = (
        ("video", "Video"),
        ("gif", "GIF"),
        ("picture", "Picture"),
        ("audio", "Audio")
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(choices=LOCATION, default=None, max_length=500, null=True)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    media_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPE, default=None)
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="media/")
    url = models.CharField(max_length=2083, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do this manually in your view.
Each time you are adding a new media or modifying a media you need to check whether the location you are setting is already in the table or not. If it is already in the table then you have to modify the former media location and set it to None.
Be careful when deleting a media because if this media has a location maybe you'll want to set the location back to another media.

Comment: How might I start implementing this? Not sure how to start this functionality as soon as I add a new media object